# python - subprocess call not terminating when using pipes

Tags: python, linux, performance, subprocess

I have a strange issue with python 2.6.5. If I call

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["ifup eth0"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

with the interface eth0 being down, the python programm hangs. "p.communicate()" takes a minute or longer to finish. If the interface is up before, the programm runs smoothly. I tested "ifup eth0" from the command line manually for both cases and its lightning fast.

If you have any idea what the Problem might be, I would appreciate it very much.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Based on the answers, I tried the following things:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["ifup", "eth0"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

If the interface was up before, the skript runs smoothly. However if the interface was down, python hangs again. I also tried:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["ifup", "eth0"], shell=False)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

And EVERYTHING runs perfektly fast. Therefore it might be indeed related to a deadlock, as pointed out funktku. However the python documentation also says [python ref](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

> Warning
>
> This will deadlock when using
>   stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the
>   child process generates enough output
>   to a pipe such that it blocks waiting
>   for the OS pipe buffer to accept more
>   data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

Therefore there shouldn't be a deadlock. Hmm... Here is the detailed output when I run the programms on the command line:

1 Case, interface eth0 already up:

```
ifup eth0
Interface eth0 already configured
```

2 Case, interface down before:

```
ifup eth0 
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running
```

So the ifup command generates two lines of ouput in case the interface is down before and one line of ouput otherwise. This is the only difference I noticed. But I doubt this is the cause of the problem, since "ls -ahl" causes many more lines of ouput and is running very well.

I also tried playing around with the buffersize argument, however no success, by setting it to some large value like 4096.

Do you have an ideas, what might be the cause of that? Or is this probably a bug in python Pipe handling or the ifup command itself? Do I really have to use the old os.popen(cmd).read()????

**EDIT2:**

os.popen(cmd).read() suffers from the same problem. Any idea of how I can test the pipe behaviour of ifup on the commandline?

I appreciate every hint, thanks in advance

Comment: I still have this problem :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[/etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate does not detach correctly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntp/+bug/1206164)

That's why read() waits until fds (stdin/stdout/stderr) are closed.
You can detach stdin/stderr/stdout (do not add stdout=subprocess.PIPE and the same to Popen constructor call).

Comment: Wow, it has been three years, but that would explain the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You should check out the [warning](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) under the `subprocess.call` method. It might be the reason of your problem.

**Warning**

> Like Popen.wait(), this will
>   deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or
>   stderr=PIPE and the child process
>   generates enough output to a pipe such
>   that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe
>   buffer to accept more data.

Comment: Can you quote the warning in your answer? Contents of an external page can change over time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however a deadlock, based on the tests i did, shouldn't be the problem as I explained in the edit to my post. If you have any more ideas, I would very much appreciate to hear from you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["ifup", "eth0"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Set `shell=False`, you don't need it.

Try running this code, it should work. Notice how two arguments are separate elements in the list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and you are perfektly right, I don't need schell = True. However unfortunatelly the above code doesn't work. Python still hangs up. Please see the additional section I have added to my post...